# Funcion que reciba una base y una potencia y retorne el exponente en c++

Tags: c++

Tengo que encontrar el valor exponente en c++ con una funcion RR (Recibe y Retorna). La pregunta como me la presentan es: Crear un programa en C, utilizando una función RR, que en la funcion main() el solicite al usuario que escriba una potencia y una base. A continuación, la función main() va imprimir el valor exponencial() que retornará como valor único.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<locale.h>

int potencia, base;
int exponencial (int exp); //Funcion Recibe Retorna

main(){ 
printf("Programa que encuentra un valor exponencial\n");
printf("---------------------------------------------\n");
printf("Escriba una potencia: "); //n1
scanf("%d",&potencia);
printf("Escriba una base: "); //n2
scanf("%d",&base);

printf("El valor exponencial es:"); 
}// Fin del main

int exponencial(int exp, int pot){ //Inicio de la funcion
int count; 

while(count==exp)
expo=exp*cont; 
printf("%d", count);  
cont++;

return cont;        
}// Fin de la función exponencial
```

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido a la comunidad. En lugar de una foto por favor ingresa el código en tu pregunta. Puedes indicarnos cuál es tu pregunta? Tal como está redactada no es claro qué es lo que deseas hacer o qué problema tiene tu código

Comment: Ya hice la modificación, esa es mi parte del main(){} en texto y tambien añadí asi como me lo escribieron lo que piden para el programa.

Comment: Gracias, puedes poner lo que tienes actualmente en tu función? Al preguntar es importante siempre incluir lo que ya tienes hecho para que las personas te puedan ayudar, recuerda que este sitio no es para que la gente resuelva tareas o proyectos y hacer preguntas sin mostrar lo intentado normalmente termina en preguntas cerradas y/o con votos negativos

Comment: Ya hice la modificacion del prototipo de mi funcion.

Comment: Perfecto, una pregunta más, lo que necesitas es calcular potencias o usar la función exponencial? Es decir si son potencias sería algo como 2 al cubo (`2 ^ 3 = 8`). Pero si es la función exponencial sería con el número `e`.

Comment: Debo calcular la funcion esponencial es decir que el usuario ingrese una potencia por ejemplo 1024, luego una base que sea por ejemplo 2. Y que la funcion calcule cual es el valor exponencial osea (10) 2^10= 1024

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Para poder calcular el exponencial es necesario contar cuántas veces puedes dividir la potencia entre la base

Por ejemplo:

```
Potencia = 8;
Base = 2;
```

Primero dividimos 8/2 y el resultado es 4

Usamos el resultado 4 y dividimos nuevamente entre la base 4/2 y el resultado es 2

Usamos nuevamente el resultado y dividimos nuevamente entre la base 2/2 y el resultado es 1

Entonces contamos el número de veces que podemos dividir potencia/base y que el resultado sea mayor a 1.

El código podría ser algo así:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int exponencial(int p, int b) {
    int c = 0;
    
    while (p > 1){
        c++;
        p /= b;
    }

    return c;
}

int main()
{
    int p, b;
    
    printf("Programa que encuentra un valor exponencial\n");
    printf("---------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Escriba una potencia: "); //n1
    scanf("%d", &p);
    printf("Escriba una base: "); //n1
    scanf("%d", &b);
    
    printf("El resultado es: %i",exponencial(p, b));

    return 0;
}
```

La línea `p /= b` significa `p = p / b` donde p es la potencia y b la base

Ten en cuenta que al utilizar una función que devuelve un entero `int` vas a tener resultados no deseados

Por ejemplo si usas como potencia 9 y como base 2 el resultado es 3, pero 2 ^ 3 es 8

Si debes calcular el valor correcto siempre entonces debes utilizar un float y hacer más consideraciones dentro de la función.